A strengthening of Vopenka's principle
I wonder if the following strengthening of Vopenka's principle is consistent and, if so, if it is equivalent to some other large cardinal principle:

Let $C$ be a proper class of models of the same language. Then for every element $\mathcal{A}$ of the class $C$ we can find another element $\mathcal{B}$ such that $\mathcal{A}$ can be elementarily embedded in $\mathcal{B}$.

I think it's inconsistent. For example, we can consider the class of all ordinals with the usual order relation. Then, $\omega$ cannot be elementarily embedded in any other ordinal. Am I wrong or is this a valid counterexample?

Your example works. If $\omega$ embeds elementarily in an ordinal $\alpha$, then $\alpha$ is infinite and has a unique element ($0$) with no immediate predecessor. The only ordinal with these properties is $\omega$ itself.
Even easier: if $A$ is finite, any elementary embedding $A\to B$ (for any $B$) is an isomorphism. So your principle fails whenever $C$ contains a finite structure $A$ and no other structure isomorphic to $A$.

Thank you very much. I was also interested in infinite structures and I wanted to check my counterexample.
